# Cannot install PECL ev package(OS X Yosemite)

Tags: terminal, php, osx-yosemite, pear, pecl

I am trying for an hour already to install the g..amn **ev** package so I can use **EvTimer** in **php** but with no success. I am running `sudo pecl install ev` in terminal but I get the following error.

```
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootTQxbPX/ev-0.2.12/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/ev/libev  -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/ev -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootTQxbPX/ev-0.2.12/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootTQxbPX/ev-0.2.12/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/ev -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/ev/libev/ev.c -o libev/ev.lo
/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootTQxbPX/ev-0.2.12/libtool: line 1280: libev/ev.loT: No such file or directory
mkdir libev/.libs
mkdir: libev: No such file or directory
make: *** [libev/ev.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

*(i can post the whole dialog if it is needed)*

I have PEAR and PECL installed but why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

This had been [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/osmanov/pecl-ev/issue/11/pecl-ev-install-fails) in version 0.2.13 of the ev package. Try `sudo pecl install ev` again.

Comment: One of the few cases where a oneliner is fine. Was this bug specific to OS X or for the package on pecl in general?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It was a general issue in `pecl-ev`'s `config.m4` file. I had to add `libev` build directory: `PHP_ADD_BUILD_DIR($ext_builddir/libev)` for "non-standard" installation prefixes.